# On page load, jquery is running before a certain div has been created

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to do a .show() on page load, however, the div is not yet loaded
It looks like jquery is running before a certain div has been created.
Wondering how can I solve this ?

my code consists of the following:

```
<script>
function choose_category(category_id)
{
    $('#' + category_id).show();   // this is the part which doesn't work, as on page load the div mentioned later is not yet available.
}
</script>

<script>
function load()
{
    choose_category('<?php echo $model->category_id->__toString(); ?>');
}
</script>

<img onload="load();" src="http://media.sociopal.com/ires/images/homepage/status-socio-icon.png" alt="" width="0" height="0" style="display:none;"></img>
```

The html embeds php code which runs a loop and generates (among other divs) the following div:

```
<div id='thecategoryid!!' onclick='choose_category("51d552eb2c8751766000016d");return false;' class = 'settings_menu_item'>
<p class='settings_menu_item_text'>Design Channels<i class='icon-chevron-right right'></i></p>
</div>
```

However, as mentioned, when the page loads (only when the page loads) the .show() does nothing because it looks like the div is not yet created.

If I debug this in chrome and go step-by-step, there is no problem (the div is created on time and the .show() works fine)

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: wrap your code in `$(document).ready({ //code });`

Comment: use jquery or javascript binding not html

Comment: you are not using any onload page handler here. If your image is cached, the onload event will be fired before the DOM is ready

Comment: The function declaration  of choose_category should not be wrapped in document ready;

The selection process happens when the function is called. Meaning that as long as the selected element exists at the time of the event, click, it should work.

Comment: Thanks Deepu. Your advice was spot on. It works properly now.

Answer (score 1):

I can see no error in the code you have posted.

It might be that your assumption of what $.show() does is wrong.

$.show simply removes any occurences of **"display: hidden;"** in the inline styling of the selected element/node.

```
<div style="color:red; display:none;">
```

would become

```
<div style="color:red;">
```

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using that inline onload stuff, try this giving your image an id (we'll use `img` here.
Since you are calling `choose_category` with an inline click event listener, **do not** place that function inside `$(document).ready` as it won't be able to be accessed.

Then, use the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = $("#img");

    img.load(function(){
        load();
    });

    if (img[0].complete)
       img.load();
});
```

What this is doing:

When the doc is ready, get the image. Attach a load event listener. If the image has already loaded by the time we got here (especially with caches), trigger a load event anyway.

Also note that you shouldn't put special put exclamation points in your id.